# I want to redirect to a fragment from one fragment onbuttonclick (jetpack naviagtion)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Im using a jetpack navigation in new androidx. In from home i have small 3 button to easily navigate to fragments that i put in navigation drawer. Since I'm not experianced in this its very confusing to me.
I have home, projects and payments.. i have to navigate from home to project and payment tab.. anyone know anyways please help me..

I GOOGLED MANY TIMES WHOLE DAY BUT NOTHING WERE HELPFUL TO ME.
i tried but failed the below code.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main, new ProjectFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

this is the naviagtion bar
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqw40.jpg)

and here is home one..

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eudmR.jpg)

since im new to this ..any help will be great.. thank you.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on the navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) and how to [tie destinations to menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer) or how to [navigate to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)?

Comment: @anhanniballake thank you bro both comment and answer give me ideas to sove the issue.

Comment: If you are using Jetpack Navigation, why do you even try to have a fragment transaction by hand? All Fragment navigation should go through the `FragmentNavigator` that is "talked to" by the `NavController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Navigation Components handle fragments transaction and back stack automatically and that's the whole point behind this component.

In your fragment:

```
findNavController().navigate(id)
```

This `id` could be either `action` id or `destination` id.

I recommend navigating by `action` id.

Actions are arrows connecting two destinations together.
Destination is another word for a fragment.

---

If you need to access your navigation inside Activity:

```
findNavController(containerId).navigate(id)
```

`constainerId` = the id of `FragmentContainerView` inside your XML.

Comment: THanks buddy it was simple and really helped me..here thank you so much..